# How to restrict non-alphabetic character to not be the first or last character of a password

Tags: html, validation, input

How do I restrict the password so it does NOT allow the first or last characters to be non-alphabetic characters (see "title")?

My HTML code:

```
<form action = "." method="post">
  <input type="password" 
    placeholder = "New Password..." 
    name= "password" 
    title = "Password must be at least 8 characters, at least one alphabetic character [a-zA-Z], at least one non-alphabetic character, which is not the first or last character." 
    pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}">
</form>
```

Example: Password hi123*HI is accepted, but how do I reject `*hi123HI` due to the fact `*` is the first character (same issue if `*` was the last character, or special characters or numbers were both the first and last characters).

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add negative lookaheads to check the initial and final characters:

```
/(?![^A-Z])(?!.*[^A-Z]$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Z]).{8,}/i
 ^^^^^^^^^^                                               NO INITIAL SPECIAL CHAR
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                  NO FINAL SPECIAL CHAR
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^                       AT LEAST ONE LETTER
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^           AT LEAST ONE SPECIAL CHAR
                                               ^^^^^^     EIGHT OR MORE CHARS
```

Comment: Torazaburo, I came up with this without using lookarounds: pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9].{8,}" and it satisfies my criterias.  What do you think?  I tried using your code, and skimed a few regex sites for knowledge, but couldn't get it too work.  Was that code for HTML or another language?  Preciate the help!

Comment: But your regexp does not enforce the rule that there be at least one alphanumeric character, and it allows a non-alphanumeric character at the end as far as I can see. This regexp works for me; see https://regex101.com/r/x8RfhV/1/. Note that `pattern` attribute will implicitly anchors `^` and `$` at the beginning and end.

Comment: Shoot, you're right.  Back to the drawing board.  I'm gonna read up on regexp more so I can understand your answer as well.